# How to get all posts if post don't have specific meta key?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, meta-query

I'm trying to add post filters based on specified post metadata. Filters works great but when I select "All types" filter doesn't reset and no posts are displayed.

HTML:

```
<select name="typefilter">
<option value="">All types</option>
<option value="type1">Type 1</option>
<option value="type2">Type 2</option>
<option value="type3">Type 3</option>
</select>

<button>Apply filters</button>
```

PHP:

```
if( isset( $_POST['typefilter'] ) ) {
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key' => 'custom_type',
        'value' => $_POST['typefilter'],
        'compare' => '='
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` condition only checks that the `typefilter` key exists in `$_POST` but not whether it's empty or not. WordPress then tries to fetch posts that have a custom field called `custom_type` with an empty value. WordPress fails to find posts that meet that criteria, hence the reason why you're not getting any results.

Within your `if` condition, check that the `typefilter` key is set **and** that it's not empty:

```
// User wants to filter posts by type
if( isset( $_POST['typefilter'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['typefilter'] ) ) {
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key' => 'custom_type',
        'value' => $_POST['typefilter'],
        'compare' => '='
    );
}
```